# how to show Jframe before Joptiopane

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I tried one code in JoptionPane. I want to show Jframe then need show popup dialog.. I done some research but not get proper answer. major code is as follows

here the code :

```
Package javaapplication1;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class home extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public home() {
        initComponents();

        Dimension dim = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        this.setLocation(dim.width/2-this.getSize().width/2, dim.height/2-this.getSize().height/2);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane,"welcome");
        // JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane,"welcome");
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code doesn't show where you display your JFrame.

Comment: it is display middle of the system...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply call `setVisible(true)` on the JFrame *before* displaying the JOptionPane. That's it.

Comment: is there any possibilities to delay to show alert message. when doing above code both are coming in same time..

Comment: @user5809644: yes, use a Swing Timer. Please google the tutorial for that as it is explained quite well.